# Any way to select a flot chart datpoint without hovering/clicking (external button)

Tags: jquery, flot

I'm looking for a way to activate a/some datapoint(s) on a jquery flot line chart by triggering a click on an external button. How could i do this - how would i get a handle on a datapoint without using the mouse - and how would i activate it and activate a tooltip?

Thanks for any expert advice!

Comment: likely need a more robust charting library for this

Comment: ok - where would you suggest i look?

Comment: actulally looking deeper in docs( Flot docs used to be very primitive)...looks like there are some `highlight/unhighlight` methods. Will play with is for a few minutes and see if I can figure something out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my previous comment I was unaware of the API hooks and methods that exist in FLOT. The old docs were a very primitive `txt` file. Here is a simple example using `highlight/unhighlight` as well as using the `pointOffset()` method to calculate a data point's pixel position in the chart in order to position a tooltip.

```
<button data-index="4">Highlight 5th point</button>
<button data-index="9">Highlight 10th point</button>
<button data-index="19">Highlight 20th point</button>
```

JS:

```
var plotData =/* data array*/

$('button').click(function(){
    var idx=$(this).data('index');
    plot.unhighlight()
    plot.highlight(dataSeriesIndex, idx);
    var dataPoint=plotData[idx];
    var position=plot.pointOffset({ x: dataPoint[0], y:  dataPoint[1] })
    var tipHTML='Data:<br> X='+dataPoint[0] +'<br> Y=' +dataPoint[1];
    $('#tooltip').css({left: position.left+10, top: position.top-10}).show().html(tipHTML)     
})
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/et87Y/73/

Comment: Very nice approach. As I dont have my points visible, the highlight method wont work. Using your tooltip method, I created my own highlight graphics on the plot.

Comment: @ddagsan ok, was working in some browsers not others due to linking to raw github for plugin source. Updated link using cdn version..try again

Answer (score 2):

Flot provides highlight and unhighlight methods on the plot object, as described in the [Plot Methods](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#plot-methods) section of the documentation.

Pass in the index of the series and the index of the point within the series, and it highlights that point.

The 'interacting' example, found in the examples folder bundled with Flot, has a live demo of this functionality.